# Find and delete matching folders based on partial name pattern

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, filenames

I have folder A of samples. I have folder B of completes. I want to delete the samples from the sample directory, when I have the complete version in folder B.

The folders will match by a common string: BAX followed by a numeric sequence (ie, BAX52858). Often the completes will have a longer filename, so it will only be a partial foldername match with that BAX##### string in common.

Thanks much~

Answer (score 0):

I don't think RegEx is really the tool for the job, in this case, but, if you are determined or required to use it for this, here's how.  Take the list of complete files from folder B, like this:

> BAX12345 
>  BAX12346 
>  BAX12347

And transform it into a pipe delimited list like this:

> BAX12345|BAX12346|BAX12347

If you want to use RegEx to perform that transformation, you could perform this RegEx replacement:

- Pattern: `\n`
- Replacement: `|`

Next, get the list of sample files like this:

> BAX12344 
>  BAX12345 
>  BAX12346 
>  BAX12347 
>  BAX12348

And then use the pipe delimited string from before as your pattern in a RegEx replace on this list of sample files:

- Pattern: `BAX12345|BAX12346|BAX12347`
- Replacement: *(empty string)*

That will result in this:

> BAX12344 
>  
>  
>  
>  BAX12348

Now you can just delete all of the files in that resulting list.  If you want to remove the empty lines, you can do so by just adding `\n` before each pipe in the pattern.

Comment: Thanks kindly for your help. I'm not determined to use regex, what would you suggest?

Comment: @MariaBaron Any programming language that allows you to access the list of files in the folders would do.  The best language for the job depends greatly on the platforms upon which you will be using it and the languages with which you are most familiar.